# Python - two variabels not adding together

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I am new to python and I was trying to make a program that did the quadratic formula but for some reason it won't add two variables together

```
#The Quadratic Formula Calculator
from cmath import sqrt

a = (int(input('Enter the value of A : ')))
b = (int(input('Enter the value of B : ')))
c = (int(input('Enter the value of C : ')))

def state_formula():
print('Calculating')

btimesb = b * b
print('First step is done, the value is', btimesb)

fourac = -4 * a * c
print ('The second step is done, the value is', fourac)

squareit = sqrt(btimesb + fourac)
print('The third step is done, the value is', squareit)

negativeb = -b
print('The fourth step is done, the value is', negativeb)

addthemplus = negativeb + squareit
print('The fith step is done, the value is', addthemplus)
```

And my it comes out as

```
Enter the value of A : 3
Enter the value of B : 3
Enter the value of C : 3
First step is done, the value is 9
The second step is done, the value is -36
The third step is done, the value is 5.196152422706632j
The fourth step is done, the value is -3
The fith step is done, the value is (-3+5.196152422706632j)
```

I was wondering why the fifth step was not actually adding the two together, I tried converting it to a float and it did not let me.

Comment: What do you mean, "not actually adding the two together"? Looks added to me. It's not like there's some simpler way to write -3+5.196152422706632j.

Comment: okay thanks, didn't know if it was right

Comment: The appended `j` indicates it's the imaginary part of a complex number. A real number `-3` plus a complex number `5.196152422706632j` is just another complex number (this time with real part): `-3+5.196152422706632j`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating the sqrt of negative value. The result is not real, but imaginary number.

In consequence all the following calculations are done in complex numbers. When you see the result such as -3+5.196152422706632j that means a complex number that consists of real(-3) and imaginary part, as signified by `j`, equal to 5.196152422706632.